# Existence of certain coprime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given $m\in\Bbb N$ large enough is there a coprime pair $a,b$ in $[2^{m-1},2^m]$ and $m_1,n_1, m_2,n_2\in[0,m^{c'}]\cap\Bbb Z$ with each of 
$$m_1a-n_1b,m_2a-n_2b\in[0,m^c]\cap\Bbb Z$$
$$m_1n_2\neq n_1m_2$$
true at some $c,c'>0$ independent of $m$?

Comment: Why are you interested in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to request is that the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}m_1 & -n_1 \\
m_2 & -n_2\end{pmatrix}$ were non-degenerate, and the vector $d:=M\binom ab$
had its coordinates of size polynomial in $m$. If this could be arranged, as
a result we would get $\binom ab=\Delta^{-1}Ad$, where $\Delta:=\det M$ is a
non-zero integer, and $A$ is a matrix with integer entries; moreover, $\Delta$
and the entries of $A$ are of size polynomial in $m$. But this would imply
$\Delta\binom ab=Ad$, which is impossible as the entries of the vector in the
left-hand side are of size exponential in $m$, while the vector in the
right-hand side has entries of size polynomial in $m$.

Comment: do you think at least $a,b$ coprime in $[2^{m-1},2^m]$ and $m,n\in[0,m^{c'}]\cap\Bbb Z$ with $ma-nb\in[0,m^c]\cap\Bbb Z$ exists? where $a,b\neq1$?

Comment: @AJ: Seems that you use $m$ to denote two different things. Also, what $a,b\ne 1$ adds to the requirement $a,b\in[2^{m-1},2^m]$? Maybe, you mean $m,n\ne 1$? And how about choosing $m=n=0$?

Comment: sorry please use $m'a-n'b$ and $m',n'\in[0,m^{c'}]\cap\Bbb Z$ and $m,n$ are non-zero.

Comment: $a=2^{m-1}$, $b=2^{m-1}+1$, $m'=n'=1$?

Comment: I meant $m,n$ not $1$ (sorry about this - $a-b=1$ I knew :) ).

Comment: For $m$ odd you can take $a=2^{m-1}+1$, $b=3\cdot2^{m-2}$, $m'=3$, and $n'=2$ (so that $m'a-n'b=3$). This should be easy to modify to cover the case of $m$ even, too.